# How to access other apps data for a backup application?

Tags: android, backup, appdata

I'm very new to android developing, and I'm making a project in my university for an app that backs up every other application's data to cloud. So in order to do this, I have to access it. Is it possible? And is there a way to do this without rooting the device?

Answer (score 0):

The app that you want to create as backup use content provider in that app for insert,add, create, delete the data.That app work like a database for you. 
For second app fetch the data from the first app.

use this link.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html